# How to add dll's without requiring any cascade dll references in ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an asp.net solution. It has 11 asp.net project and 1 asp.net website. Suppose that project's name are A, B, C, D, E ... etc. And also some of these are called in another one. For example, project B(Logging Module) calls project A(Database Interface Module). 
I want to add only B's dll to my website. I added B's dll to website and compiled website and then A's dll automatically came into website's bin directory. I am searching an answer for this problem for 4-5 days but I didn't find any..

Comment: How are you adding the references? If you add them as project references, you won't have this problem.

Comment: Why don't you want A's DLLs pulled in? If `B.DLL` depends on `A.DLL`, then surely you'll encounter exceptions if it isn't pulled in?

Comment: I added a post build event and compiled dll's go to under the "DLL's" folder. And I added references from this path. If I add them as project reference, then website project's compilation requires these project's compilation again.

Comment: Rob: I don't want any access directly to Database Module.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to put .dll's in your bin folder and the project will be able to use them.